# ios swift bluetooth reconnection

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I got an app which connects with a BLE product. This product might get disconnected when it is used but it should automatically reconnect whenever it is near the iPhone if the bluetooth is on.

To keep it simple and say that the bluetooth of this product is turned on by pressing a button. So, the user walked away from the BLE device, both get disconnected and they should reconnect when they are both on. But! This does not really happen in my implementation.

My attempt to solve this problem was by implementing the following:

Adding the right background modes `Info.plist` which are `bluetooth-central` and `bluetooth-peripheral`.

Besides that I've added the `options` in the parameters of the `CBManager`  to wake the app up if the app gets killed by the system with the following statement:

`centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:identifier])`

and I've implemented the following:

`public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {
    print("Am I restoring?")
}`

But I am not able to test if the BLE device automatically reconnects when the app is killed by the system. Is there a proper way to test this 'feature'?

And besides that, the main problem is still there. When I kill the app, the BLE device in the bluetooth setting is disconnected. How can I prevent that?

My device is sending some data when I press the button and when its disconnected, it starts to search for devices so I think that should be atleast fine.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? If so, could you please share how did you manage it? I am having similar problem, I need to check if the device suddenly (unpredictably) disconnects and handle that event (when bluetooth is still on). The only way I think of is making a timer and invoking a check method like every 10s or so..

Comment: Not sure if there's any way to fix this problem. If your app is killed that's that.

With that being said, it should still be able to maintain a connection (or a periodic one) in the background.